# What is the best way to set if condition in java script for multiple variables equals same value then do nothing else do something

Tags: javascript

there are 5 variables if all is populated then check if each one equals to same value then don't do anything if all are populated and any of these 5 variables is not equal to same value then do something.

can we have empty if I tried below but looking for best ans in javascript

```
if ( (var1=="--- all ---")&&(var2=="--- all ---") &&(var3=="--- all ---") &&(var4=="--- all ---") &&(var5=="--- all ---"))  {//do nothing}

else {
console.log('do the thing');
}
```

Comment: `[var1, var2, var3, var4, var5].every(e => e === "--- all ---")`

Comment: If your variables are actually like var1, var2 etc, you need an array, not a bunch of vars.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all variables and  check against the first element and if not equal perform something.

```
if ([var1, var2, var3].some((v, _, a) => a[0] !== v)) {
    console.log('do the thing');
}
```

ES5

```
if ([var1, var2, var3].some(function (v, _, a) { return a[0] !== v; })) {
    console.log('do the thing');
}
```

Comment: How to write this in traditional javascript as am new to js looks like you wrote it in es6 advance

Comment: What is v_ and a as argument doing in function? IS it like `if ([var1, var2, var3].some(function (v, _, a) {
  return a[0] !== v;
})) {
  console.log('do the thing');
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap them in an array to check all values, like this:

```js
let var1;
let var2;
let var3;
let var4;
let var5;

if ([var1, var2, var3, var4, var5].every(value => value == "--- all ---")) {
  //do nothing
}
else {
  console.log('do the thing');
}
```

Comment: A potential "gotcha" with this is that the `every` method will always return true for an empty array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: probably better to negate the output of `.every()`, so then you don't need a redundant block of code after the `if`

Comment: It would be better to have a function that is more human readable, but I just replicated the example he asked with the improvement in how to check the condition. And it would be even better to use a composition and have a `when` or `branch` function instead of `if` statements.